# Polynomial Remainder Theorem seems to use divide by zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The Khan Academy [proof of Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/arithmetic-with-polynomials/polynomial-remainder-theorem/v/polynomial-remainder-theorem-proof) (PRT) uses polynomial/algebraic long division:

$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{f(x)}{b(x)} =& q(x) &+ \frac{r(x)}{b(x)} \\
  f(x)              =& q(x)b(x) &+ r(x)
\end{align}
$$

If $b(x) = (x-a)$, then $f(a) = q(a)(a-a) + r(a) = q(a)\cdot 0 + r(a)$, and therefore $f(a) = r(a)$.  Since $r(x)$ must be a constant (being lower degree than $(x-a)$), it's the same for all $x$ we get $f(a) = r$.

Isn't the first line undefined for division by $b(x)=x-a$ when $x=a$, because $b(a)=0$? i.e. it's divsion by zero?

1. Is it OK, because in getting from the first line to the second line, it isn't "multiplied" by $b(x)$, but is "rewritten"? That is, it's a syntactic operation, not a numerical one, therefore we don't have to worry about divsion by zero.  I don't think so, because then we could use the same argument for differentiation in calculus.
2. Is it because limits always exist for polynomials with a factor cancelled out? This would mean we could skip epison-delta limits for polynomial differentiation (as I believe Newton did), and just say for $f(x)=x^2$, that $f'(x) = \frac{x^2+2ax+a^2 - x^2}{a} = 2x + a$ and as $a$ goes to zero, $f'(x)=2x$.  Limits wouldn't be mentioned for PRT, because it's covered before limits have been introduced (in calculus).

If the second point is correct, PRT would (technically) be written with limits

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = r$$

Answer (score 2):

You just start from the second line.

Polynomial division is a process of decomposing a polynomial $f(x)$ into a sum $q(x)b(x)+r(x)=f(x)$. As you can see, you don't *divide* anything here in an arithmetical sense. All you do is performing an algorithm that produces the decomposition $q(x)b(x)+r(x)$ out of $f(x)$, the only worry you could have is that you divide by zero in the algorithm; but that isn't the case.

Well, you could say that this is the 1. answer. I think that it is important to say that no arithmetical division is taking place at all, other than what's done in the algorithm. So you don't even write $\dfrac{f(x)}{b(x)}$.

You don't have to use limits, because you don't divide by anything. But you *can* if you feel comfortable with it. Polynomial division came earlier  than limits in the history of mathematics, so you can view "not writing the first line" as a workaround to not using limits/divide by zero.

There is one more thing, which is more subtle. When using polynomial division, you don't divide numbers, you divide *polynomials* and polynomials aren't numbers. As long as you don't want to divide by the zero polynomial ($f(x)=0$) (because you can't divide by zero everywhere) then you are good to go. Polymonials are entities of their own, independent of "plugging in values". And your concern is that *plugging in* $a$ can make polynomial division meaningless (i.e. there would be a division by zero). But polynomials can divide just fine without any substitutions, and only *after* the process, when you are just left with the identity $f(x)=q(x)b(x)+r(x)$, you can plug in $a$.

In other words, you use a tool (the polynomial divison) from a polynomial world to do something in your "arithmetical" world. In the arithmetical world, "polynomials" are just *functions* that take a number and split out a number, and your concern is competely valid. But in a polynomial world, the polynomial $x-a$ isn't a zero polynomial, so it is competely safe to divide by it.

(The ending here sounds like a fairly tale; it was my attempt at describing [polynomial rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) with layman terms, hope it sounded at least plausible.)

Comment: Thanks. I think it will help when I fully grasp how polynomial division finds a factor - I can see that it always works (eliminating the present leading term just adjusts the others), and you could continue with negative exponents (if wanted)... but not how it gets a factor, except that it's division. `[P]olynomials aren't numbers` is like my note `1` - couldn't the same argumennt apply to calculus: *we aren't doing arithmetic (yet), it's just polynomials, so we can cancel out the `a`* (as in my note `2`. I feel calculus would be easier to understand if taught that way.

Comment: In calculus, you *are* doing arithmetic. The division in the definition of a derivative *is* a *true* arithmetic division. It is because you should be able to calculate the derivative of *any* function, not only polynomials. If you are dealing with polynomials only then... well, you are right. But it is rare.