# $f(a) = 0 \implies (x-a) \mid f(x)$? (polynomial zeros imply factors)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Hopefully this is a foolish question with a simple answer.

I've seen it said that, for polynomial $f(x)$

$$
f(a)=0 \iff (x-a) \mid f(x)
$$

I can see the implication from factor to zero: $(x-a) \mid f(x) \implies f(a)=0$, because anything multiplied by zero is zero, and if $x=a$, then $(x-a) = 0$.

But I'm not sure of the converse: $f(a) = 0 \implies (x-a) \mid f(x)$.

If $f(a)=0$, is the *only* way it can be zero is if it includes a factor $(x-a)$? How can we be sure there isn't some other circumstance that could make it zero? I guess I'm looking for a proof.

Hopefully it is a foolish question and simple answer!

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, see [Factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Answer (score 7):

Here is an explicit way of showing it. A general polynomial can be written on the form
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^n$$
From this we have that $f(x) - f(a)$ is given by
$$f(x) - f(a) = a_1(x-a) + a_2 (x^2-a^2) + \ldots + a_n (x^n - a^n)\tag{1}$$
Now we can try to factor each of the terms above:
$$\begin{align}x^2-a^2 &= (x-a)(x+a)\\x^3-a^3 &= (x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)\\x^4-a^4 &= (x-a)(x^3+ax^2+a^2x + a^3)\end{align}$$
and in general $x^k - a^k = (x-a)(x^{k-1} + ax^{k-2} + \ldots + a^{k-2}x + a^{k-1})$. This shows that every term on the right hand side of $(1)$ is divisible by $(x-a)$ so in general $(x-a) \mid f(x) - f(a)$. A special case of this is that if $f(a) = 0$ then $(x-a) \mid f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! In getting the formula $x^k-a^k$, I can guess that when you multiply the series by $x$ and take away the series multiplied by $a$, all the terms in the middle must cancel out, leaving those at the ends - but I can't see how the details actually do that, nor work out how to see it. It seems it should be easy, using $\Sigma$ sums with indices, but I'm not making much progress.

Comment: @hyperpallium That's exactly how it works. Making a proof for the general case is not that hard: we compute $(x-a)\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}a^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k+1}a^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}a^{k+1}$ and by changing the summation index $k+1 \to K$ in the last sum it becomes $\sum_{K=1}^{n+1} x^{n-K+1}a^{K}$ and you can see that the two sums exactly cancel excepts for $k=0$ in the first term and $K=n+1$ in the last term which leaves us with $x^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! My attempt was similar.... I think I can see it from the difference, $\Sigma - \Sigma$  I'll need to sit down and go through this step by step myself - the complexity is a too much for me, and any little misunderstanding trips me up. The $n$ here is $k-1$ from the answer; the $k$ here is an index. The change of index "$k+1 \to K$" I haven't seen before in concept or notation.

Comment: Oh! I see, "the last sum" is (of course) the second $\Sigma$, I thought it meant the $\Sigma + -\Sigma$ (since subtraction is an addition of a negated operand... a little knowledge is a dangerous thing).  So, the summed amount(?) is identical to the first $\Sigma$, only the indices differ, making it as you say, very clear which ones cancel out. Nice! I end up learning more about the methods than the result - which is what I really need!

Answer (score 4):

You can divide $f(x)$ by $(x-a)$ to get $$f(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(x)$$ where $\deg(r) < \deg(x-a)=1$. Therefore $\deg(r)= 0$ so $r$ is a constant and we can drop the $x$.
Now evaluate at $a$:
$$f(a) = q(a)(a-a) + r$$

The LHS is zero by assumption, the RHS is equal to $r$. Thus $r=0$ and $(x-a)$ divides $f(x)$ without remainder.

$\,$

Edit: It seems to me like you're confused about why polynomial division always works, so here's the proof to clear things up.

**Theorem.** For any $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$, $g(x) \neq 0$, there exist $q(x), r(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $$f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$$ and where $\deg(r) < \deg(g)$.

*Proof*: First, choose any $q(x), r(x)$ such that the above equation is satisfied; i.e. $q(x) = 0, r(x) = f(x).$ If $\deg(r) < \deg(g)$, we are done.

Therefore assume $\deg(r) \geq \deg(g)$. Let $r(x) = r_nx^n + r_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + r_0$, $g(x) = g_mx^m + g_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \dots + g_0$.
Now let $r'(x) = r(x) - x^{n-m}r_ng_m^{-1}g(x)$, let $q'(x) = q(x) + x^{n-m}r_ng_m^{-1}$. Then $\deg r' < \deg r$ (just look at the coefficient of $x_n$) and again we have $$f(x) = q'(x)g(x) + r'(x).$$

If $\deg(r') < \deg(g)$ now, we can stop. If not, repeat the above with $q'$ and $r'$. Because $\deg(r) < \infty$, this procedure must stop after finitely many iterations, so eventually we will have a remainder of degree less than $\deg(g)$.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks! I can follow this, but don't "get" it. BTW I see that $r(x)$ being a constant is crucial, so that $r(x)=0$ for all x, not just for $x=a$.

Comment: This proof means that there *could be* some weird interaction between a polynomial's terms that lead to $f(a)=0$... and if that happens, the terms can be rewritten as having a factor of $(x-a)$. e.g. for $f(x)=x^2-2x$, there's a weird interaction for $x=2$ where the terms cancel $f(2)=2^2-2\cdot 2=0$, which this proof says means $f(x)$ can be written with a factor of $(x-2)$. Which it can be: $x^2-2x = x(x-2)$. This is astonishing to me, partly because it's non-constructive, just showing it must be true, not how. But, using polynomial long division, we *can* construct the other factor $q(x)$.

Comment: This proof relies on it *always* being possible to rewrite $f(x)$ as $q(x)(x-a)+r(x)$, Polynomial Remainder Theorem (PRT). I don't fully "get" polynomial long division, and perhaps getting that will enable me to "get" PRT and the proof given here. I do get the *algorithm* of polynomial long division, and why it always works - but not why it means $f(x)$ can be written as a term  $q(x)b(x)$ with the divisor $b(x)$ as a factor, and a remainder term $r(x)$. It makes sense to  multiply the division form by divisor, but not as polynomials (also, divide by zero ($b(x)=(x-a), b(a)$) is undefined).

Comment: Sorry to spam your answer with all these thoughts, but I'd really like to "get" and I'm troubled that I don't. I probably should ask another question about polynomial long division.

Comment: I've added a proof for the existence of a polynomial division algorithm. The resulting $q(x), r(x)$ are unique too.
Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for going to the trouble of adding this! Well, it's going beyond Khan Academy High School, but I have a smattering of other math, and I have wikipedia, so I'll give it a go!

Comment: $\Bbb Q[x]$ is the set of all rational polynomials (i.e. with coefficients from $\Bbb Q$). It's a *commutative ring* - like the integers - so has $+$, $-$, $*$... but not $/$. That is, this set is equipped with an **addition** operator (associative, commutative, identity), additive inverse (enabling **subtraction**); and a multiplication operator (associative, identity), but *not* a multiplicative inverse (so **no division**), but can be commutative or not (polynomials do have commutative muliplication, so they're a "*communtative* ring"). Finally, multiplcation distributes over addition.

Comment: I think the significance of all this is (1) we can treat polynomials as mathematical objects, without ever evaluating them; (2) like integers, we can only have a division with remainder.

Comment: OK, we iteratively shift multiples of $g(x)$ from $r'(x)$ to $q'(x)g(x)$, until $deg(r')<deg(g)$, where a "multiple" is a one-term rational polynomial. Although coefficents can be zero, the leading coefficient never is, and we only ever divide by that (i.e. divide by $g_m$). I think, if we count every term in $f(x)$ (i.e. even if its coefficient is zero), I think this takes exactly $deg(f)-deg(g)+1$ steps? (We *could* continue, lowering $deg(r')$ further, but would get negative exponents, which aren't ploynomials.)

Comment: Thanks, this is great - there's no "divison", only multiplication and add/sub. I follow it, but I'll have to wait for it to sink in before I see if it's enough for its role in your answer to make sense to me... Also, I previously asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768747/polynomial-remainder-theorem-seems-to-use-divide-by-zero) about $g(x)\ne 0$, and yet the proof here and Factor Theorem use exactly that ($g(x)=(x-a), g(a)=0$) Oh! Wait, the non-zero part here means non-zero polynomial ($g(x)=0$), not that it happens to *evaluate* to zero for some particular $x$).

Comment: It might take less than $\deg(f) - \deg(g) + 1$ steps as we might cancel out not only the highest power but, by chance, the next highest ones as well. It seems like you understood everything else perfectly well though.

Comment: Thanks! I see. I realized my main trouble was with $r(x)=0 \implies g(x) \mid f(x)$. Your polynomial division shows that $f(x)=q'(x)g(x)+r'(x)$ at each step. By definition, $g(x) | q'(x)g(x)$. If $r'(x)=0$, then $f(x)=q'(x)g(x)$, and therefore $g(x) \mid f(x)$. I worked through examples covering all the cases, but it's still a little hard for me to really *see* that taking away multiples of $g(x)$ means we get a factor, but I see it's true. (I think my issue is also present in long division of integers, with different powers of 10. I should probably revisit tha! Then apply it to polynomials.)

Comment: I still don't fully see it, but maybe expecting too much. I can see **integer** division as marking off lengths of the divisor, with the "remainder" left over, but this visualization doesn't apply to **polynomial** division (is there one?).  It makes sense to divide the **leading terms** in polynomial division, but what happens to the lower terms is arbitrary, like a slot machine or leaves tossed in the air. Whereas, in **long division** of integers, the choice of quotient is affected by lower column (terms).

Comment: Polynomial terms are like independent dimensions that can't overflow when multiplied (and can just become negative when subtracted). Dividing the leading terms *might* have been like integer division, but if our polynomials are over a field (e.g. $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$ - is that how you say it? Yes, *"polynomial ring, K[X], in X over a field K*" Are polynomials *always* over a field? No, *ring*), then we can always divide with no remainder. Again, sorry to spam you with these follow ups - but do you think my understanding is good enough, and there's no neat intuitive visualization I'm missing?